# Drag & Drop with Vanilla JavaScript in small screen & mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a drag & drop events (to move text) in my webpage. It is working fine in the big screens, but when I try it on small screens (less than 480) the event fires, but the text either disappears or the touch grabs the screen behind the `div` (the body of the page itself)

JS

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

const ele = document.getElementById("textOverImage");

if (innerWidth <= 480) {
    ele.addEventListener('touchstart', handleStart, false);
    ele.addEventListener('touchend', handleEnd, false);
    ele.addEventListener('touchmove', handleMove, false);

    function handleStart(s) {
        console.log('touch started');

        x = s.clientX;
        y = s.clientY;

        document.querySelector("#lock_image").addEventListener('touchmove', handleMove);
        document.querySelector("#lock_image").addEventListener('touchend', handleEnd);
    };

    function handleMove(s) {
        console.log('touch moved');

        const dx = s.clientX - x;
        const dy = s.clientY - y;

        ele.style.top = `${ele.offsetTop + dy}px`;
        ele.style.left = `${ele.offsetLeft + dx}px`;

        ele.classList.remove('centered');
        ele.classList.remove('customClass');
        ele.classList.add('customMovement');

        x = s.clientX;
        y = s.clientY;
    };

    function handleEnd() {
        console.log('touch ended');
        document.querySelector("#lock_image").removeEventListener('touchmove', handleMove);
        document.querySelector("#lock_image").removeEventListener('touchend', handleEnd);
    };
}
```

Comment: You have to `preventDefault()` in the move methods etc, no?

Comment: I did add it but still it holds the main dom not the targeted div

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 480){
        ele.addEventListener('touchstart', handleStart, false);
        ele.addEventListener('touchend', handleEnd, false);
        ele.addEventListener('touchmove', handleMove, false);

        function handleStart(s){
          s.preventDefault();

          x = s.touches[0].clientX;
          y = s.touches[0].clientY;

          console.table(x, y);

          document.querySelector("#lock_image").addEventListener('touchmove', handleMove);
          document.querySelector("#lock_image").addEventListener('touchend', handleEnd);
        };

        
        
        function handleMove(s){
          s.preventDefault();

          const dx = s.touches[0].clientX - x;
          const dy = s.touches[0].clientY - y;
          
          ele.style.top = `${ele.offsetTop + dy}px`;
          ele.style.left = `${ele.offsetLeft + dx}px`;
          
          
          ele.classList.remove('centered');
          ele.classList.remove('customClass');
          ele.classList.add('customMovement');
          
          x = s.touches[0].clientX;
          y = s.touches[0].clientY;
        };
        
        function handleEnd(s){
          s.preventDefault();
          document.querySelector("#lock_image").removeEventListener('touchmove', handleMove);
          document.querySelector("#lock_image").removeEventListener('touchend', handleEnd);
        };


      }
```